# Hide subsite pages from navigation

Tags: navigation

There are two basic options on SharePoint 2010 navigation ignoring the one that only shows the parent:

1. Display the current site, the navigation items below the current site, and the current site's siblings
2. Display only the navigation items below the current site

The first is the default when you create a new site and works okay until you've got a very complex structure and the navigation bar becomes too busy.

So we've started switching to the second style except the functionality of that options isn't quite what we expected. See this screenshot:

http://www.picpaste.com/9d14916f561174bb022a383471c0c2cd.png

Citrix XenApp is the site. Procedures is a child site underneath. Old information, repair clipboard chain etc. are pages in the parent site.

Question is - how do we stop the navigation showing the pages under the Procedures child site? We don't want it to go down two levels. Just one is fine.

If the inbuilt navigation control cannot do this, are there alternative 3rd party navigation controls?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by going into the subsite's navigation options and deselect the option that says "Show pages"

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the page settings through "view all site content" there is a check box that states whether you want to show the page.